# Search through on Linux files and filter out specific string and remove everything else

Tags: linux, sed, grep, search

I am trying to find an efficient way of searching through a whole set of files in a directory and only looking for a specific string up to the first comma.

Example of the postgres log file:

```
Apr 27 03:35:18 test postgres[24098]: [5-1] user=postgres,db=postgres,app=psqlclient=127.0.0.1
Apr 27 03:35:18 test postgres[24098]: [5-2] user=postgres,db=postgres,app=psqlclient=127.0.0.1
```

I am only interested in the username used in the files. I could use pgbadger and look at it via HTML but would be quite time consuming.

So as an example, I would be able to see just :

```
user=postgres
```

As opposed to the whole set of text before and after the user.

However I am looking for any user not specifically postgres.

I have tried using grep on files but I only see results on just user=postgres.

Is there anyway of searching through a set of files for say user= up until the first comma as an example?

Or even search every file and remove anything that is before user= in each row, I could then maybe put into excel to get the result I need.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/user=/{gsub(/^.*user=|,.*$/, "");print $0}' file
```

If you want to display `user=` and filename, then the command may be changed.

```
awk '/user=/{gsub(/^.*user=|,.*$/, "");
printf "%s:user=%s\n",FILENAME,$0}' *.log
```

In this command, if `user=` is found, then
`gsub()`function taking characters from start of record to`user=`and following comma after`user`to end of record changes them to empty string(`""`).

Comment: Thanks @prabhjot-singh for this, I will likely utilise this as it gives me the results I need.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GNU grep` with `PCRE`:

```
grep -Po -- '(?<=user=).+?(?=,)' *.log
```

If you like to display the `user=` keyword too:

```
grep -o -- 'user=[^,]*' *.log
```

you can even display the file in which the match succeeded by adding the `-H`  option to the `grep` command above (without it, the file name is only displayed if there is more than one file specified).

So the `grep` command become:

```
grep -Ho -- 'user=[^,]*' *.log
```

And the output:

```
pgsql.log:user=postgres
pgsql.log:user=postgres
```

Comment: Thanks @danielegrassini for this.